# Limit of items selected in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, export-to-excel

I have found and deployed a nice .wsp package that allow you to select items in a sharepoint list or filter a list and it will only export the selected/filtered items.  The catch is, you have to select all the items before you click on the 'export' button.  If I filter the list and it returns more than 100 items, I can not select the whole list to export - SharePoint has a limit that you can only select up to a 100 items in a list.  Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: In the view setting (Modified View), you can limit of displayed list items (Number of items to display).

Comment: Thank you Fox, but the client needs to export all filtered items, even if it is more than 100.  For the Export to Excel wsp to work, you have to select all items, and if it more than 100, you can not select them.

Comment: Nonsense....:()

Comment: Fox, I think you might misunderstand me.  For example, the client wants to export all items created since January to March in 2018.  Which can be 198 items.  For this custom .wsp export function to work, you need to select the items in your list that you want to export, but Sharepoint does not allow you to select more than 100 items.  Therefor, the client can not select all 198 filtered items to export with the custom export to excel function.  (I know when you have a list and you use the built-in SharePoint export to excel function, it will export all.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a filtered view of the list then export that view to Excel, this is OOTB functionality.

Comment: Thank you evilfoamy, but the client want to use different criteria for each export to excel. A filtered view is fixed on the criteria you set it up with